# Negation of a string in a regex

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I realise that something similar has been asked before, but I can't seem to fit the solution to what I am trying to do, so please don't just think this is a dupe.

I have a string in the style `{block:string}contents{/block:string}`, which can be matched fairly easily with `{block:([a-z_-\s]+)}.*{/block:\1}`

What I want to do is modify the inner .* part so that it does *not* match any string that has a `{block:[a-z_-\s]+}` between it, that is all {block}{/block} that have a {block} inside them should not be matched.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
{block:([a-z_-\s]+)}[^{]*(?!{block:([a-z_-\s]+)}.*{\block:\2})[^}]*{/block:\1}
```

I am pretty mediocre at regex, but the negative lookahead bounded by the [^{]* and [^}]* statements should keep your matches tag-free.

Comment: Is it failing to match or is PHP's regex giving you an error?

Answer (score 2):

Compressed: `m~\{block:([a-z\s_-]+)\}(?:(?!\{/?block:\1\}).)*\{/block:\1\}~xs`

Example in Perl:

```
$_ = '{block:string}conte{block:string}nts{/block:string}{/block:string}';

if ( m~    # match operator

        \{block: ([a-z\s_-]+) \}   # opening block structure and capt grp 1

        (?:                        # begin non capt grp
            (?! \{/?block: \1 \} )     # negative lookahead, don't want backreffed
                                       # open or closed block struct    
            .                          # ok, grab this character
        )*                         # end group, do 0 or more times (greedy)

        \{/block: \1 \}            # closing block structure matching grp 1 

  ~xs )    # modifiers: expanded, include newlines 

{
   print "matched '$&'\n";
}
```

Output:
matched '{block:string}nts{/block:string}'

Comment: Thanks Alan. Should bite the bullet, been putting off PHP for too long.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$ptn = "%(?:{block:[a-z_\s-]+})(?![^}]*?{block:).*?{/block:[a-z_\s-]+}%";
$str = "... your content here ...";
preg_match_all($ptn, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

For example:

```
$str = "{block:string}test2{/block:string} {block:string}contents{block:string}{block:string}test3{/block:string}{/block:string}{/block:string} sdf ";
```

Would produce:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => {block:string}test2{/block:string}
        [1] => {block:string}test3{/block:string}
    )
)
```

Comment: I can't tell if his backref was important but your regex matches `"{block:stringa}nts{/block:string}"`

Comment: I assumed (maybe incorrectly) that the back reference was a result of trying to match tags when they were nested. You may be right that `{block:abc}content{/block:def}` could exist and is invalid. If so,  now he is aware that it needs to be fixed. :)